# PostCSS not purging

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I am on Windows 10 with Node v14.15.4 and npm 6.14.10

I have executed below command successfully

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest postcss-cli cssnano onchange
```

This has no effect :

```
"tw:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production postcss build ./src/css/tailwind.css -o ./public/css/tailwind.css",
```

If I remove `SET NODE_ENV=production` it works but public/css/tailwind.css is still 3.2MB.

```
"tw:prod": "postcss build ./src/css/tailwind.css -o ./public/css/tailwind.css",
```

Why isn't it purging ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to create a [configuration file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#create-your-configuration-file) and provide the paths of your templates in [the purge option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#basic-usage).

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.vue',
    './src/**/*.jsx',
  ],
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: All this is done. There's something wrong with the windows command, `SET NODE_ENV=production & postcss build ...`